# How to extract URL from link (link feature, not HYPERLINK formula) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets allows to specify (hyper)links in two ways:

- By using [HYPERLINK formula/function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en), e.g. `=HYPERLINK("http://example.com/", "Example.com")`
- By using ["linking" feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?hl=en) – `Insert » Insert Link`

There are a lot of solutions around the web, and StackOverflow, for extracting URL from the first option - the HYPERLINK formula, but **I haven't found any way how to extract it from the second option.**

[image: screenshot]

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RNn4iVDgROwtYTqYdUhvgxdbF1WItb9rs5j203DhDpA/edit)

Comment: I do not think that this is possible with a sheets formula, but it is possible with a simple Apps Script custom funciton - if you are interested.

Comment: @ziganotschka AppsScript would be great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### How to extract with Apps Script a link URL inserted with `Insert » Insert Link`

- Apps Script has a class `https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value` that allows you to retrieve not only the plain text contained in a cell, but also its properties, such as the link URL.
- To access this property use the method [getRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue) combined with [getLinkUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getlinkurl)

**Sample to retrieve the link URL in a custom function:**

```js
function getLink(range){
  var link = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  return link;
}
```

After writing and saving this code, you simply need to call it from any cell, giving it the reference of the cell with the link URL as parameter.

**Important:**

Since it is the reference and not the value of the cell that should be passed to the function, you need to put the A1 notation in quotes.

**Sample:**

`=getLink("A1")`

[image]

Comment: I have tried this in several google sheet workbooks and using many different links. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it does not. When it doesn't work the cell shows the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLinkUrl' of null (line 2)." I can't figure out why this happens. But each time I open a fresh workbook it works.

Comment: This is the error message I would expect if you run the function directly from the editor or if you call it without parameters - the function expects an A1 notation of a cell to work correctly. In any case: Try to use `SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX").getSheetByName("YYY").getRange(range).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();` to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: @ziganotschka it works! Thank you so so much! I added a new sheet with your solution to the example spreadsheet mentioned in my question.

Comment: I keep getting `Error: An unknown error has occurred, please try again later.` while trying to run this in the Script Editor. Any idea why this might happen? Spreadsheets API is on if that matters.

Answer (score 6):

We can improve [ziganotschka's solution](/a/63699876) to avoid the need for quotation marks.

Enter this in **B1** (assuming text with the embedded link is in **A1**):

```
=getLink(ADDRESS(row(),column(A1)))
```

This way it can be dragged down to quickly get data for an entire column.

Answer (score 4):

If want to use like normal formula without quotation marks,

```
function GetURL(input) {
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var rx = /=geturl\((.*)\)/gi;
  var rng_txt = rx.exec(formula)[1]
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rng_txt);
  return rng.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()
}
```